# How to use history.push(/nextpath) or windows.location?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a div (images) in stories.jsx file that I need to give it `onClick` function. How do I make `handeClick` function that will make me go to the next page, to story.jsx (story API)? This API will display a different story for every div(image) it has when clicked on the one of them.

My images are in public(static) folder, and I saved them in MongoDB with `name`,`storyText` and `imagePath`. But I need a handle function with `history.push(/nextpath)`, to get me to the 1 of story pages, depending on what image I click. Either that or a function that gives me the id when I press on the image and then takes me to the image with `window.location`.

I don't know either, I am a newbie. How would I exactly use `history.push(/nextpath)` or the other thing, with an actual example? Here is my `this.state` and under it is `render(){}` from my stories.jsx file. What do I do?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
```

This gets all images to story.jsx:

```
router.get("/slike", (req, res) => {
  Slike.find((err, result) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

This gets a single image from stories.jsx:

```
router.get("/slike/:id", (req, res) => {
  Slike.findById(req.params.id, (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: you are using react-router-dom?

Comment: I do, but not on these 2 files, I use it for routing the rest of the app, but even that I wouldnt know how to use here

Comment: in react i mean express on your server if you want to path param to route check this :https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to do that.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory();
history.push('/path_to_go')
```